# How do I delete a website in Visual Studio online?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

How do I delete a website in Visual Studio online? 
I am able to delete Collections but not a single site.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the administration context for the team project collection by choosing the [image]
   gear icon. 
   Open the context menu for the team project that you want to delete.

[image] 
You’ll only see this option when you’re a member of the Project Collection Administrators group. 
Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547204.aspx) to learn how to get added to this group. 
 2. You must select the check box in order to initiate the delete operation.
[image]
[Link for full details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357756.aspx)

Comment: Personal it's a Team Project and i have many websites inside.

And i don't get the delete on their context menu.


Should the structure be instead:

DefaultCollection/Websites
as opposed to

DefaultCollection/Project(personal)/Websites



[link]http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7326/12426226513_9453ec1cdc_o.jpg
[link]http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3806/12426074395_887843050c_o.jpg